# What is the best way to call render on multiple instances of a view?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm attempting to call render on multiple instances of a view. However they kind-of need to happen in order (not really). Here is my view code which hopefully will explain itself.

```
var SiteView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#contentArea',
    render: function(siteId) {
        console.log("SiteView.render running",arguments);
        var that = this;
        var siteCollection = new SiteCollection();
        this.collection = siteCollection;
        this.collection.fetch({
            data: {
                returnType: "VERTEX",
                startId: siteId,
            },
            success: function(model, response, options) {
                console.log("SiteView.render.success",arguments);
                var templateHtml = _.template(siteHtml, response);
                that.$el.empty();
                that.$el.html(templateHtml);
                that.renderServersList(response.ID);
                that.renderContainersList(response.ID);
            }
        });
    },
    renderServersList: function(siteId) {
        console.log("SiteView.getServersList running", arguments);
        var that = this; // Removed this line which seemed to be causing the issue :-/
        // This is a view in a separate file provided by require.js
        var serverListView = new VertexListView({el: "#siteServersListBody"});
        serverListView.render("SERVERS", siteId);
    },
    renderContainersList: function(siteId) {
        console.log("SiteView.getContainersList running", arguments);
        // This is a view in a separate file provided by require.js
        var contListView = new VertexListView({el: "#siteContainersListBody"});
        contListView.render("CONTAINERS", siteId);
    }
});
```

Both the getContainersList and getServersList is working, as in it's getting the proper data. However, as the server list is rendering, it also contains the entire containers list and then the containers list only contains what it is supposed to contain.

The reason why I'm separating out these requests instead of including the containers and servers in the original request is mainly because of the size of the containers. It can be rather large.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you presented this without domain-specific application code. Where are the multiple instances of a view? The title of this question suggests a simple answer (iterate through an array of views; arrays in JS always has a fixed order), but the code block is not the best thing to look at if you've not been starting at it for a while, like you probably have been.

Comment: Consider managing subviews with https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter

Comment: The reason for my first comment is why force people to try understanding your code when you have two functions called "get" that don't return anything.

Comment: Sorry about the get... that's just habit, my partners complain about that also. Those methods should probably be called render... I'll edit the code to make it read a little better.

The multiple instances are actually local to each of the renderServersList and renderContainersList functions. I create a new VertexListView in each. However, when the serverList is rendered, it also contains the containers which I really don't understand as they're separate objects.

Comment: OK, kind-of a WTF moment... while going through this yet again, I noticed the "var that = this;" line in the renderServersList. I was thinking, why is that there? So I removed it and now it works as expected. Which now I'm totally confused as to why that would make a difference. Don't get me wrong, glad it works, but why would that cause it to not work? OK guys, thanks for the responses. Of course I welcome a better way if I'm going about this totally wrong as I am a backbone newb :).